# Converting Access Pivot queries to Mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot, crosstab

I am trying to figure out how to convert this crosstab query to its equivalent in mysql. Any help will be of highly appreciated.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(QryMainCrosstab.Bene_Act) AS SumOfBene_Act
SELECT QryMainCrosstab.DistrictCode, QryMainCrosstab.District_Name AS District
FROM QryMainCrosstab
WHERE (((QryMainCrosstab.Month)=[Forms]![frmResponseReport]![txtMonth]))
GROUP BY QryMainCrosstab.DistrictCode, QryMainCrosstab.District_Name
PIVOT QryMainCrosstab.StrategicResponse;
```

The QryMainCrossTab is another sql query.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a *pivot* function but it can be replicated using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

The code would be similar to the following:

```
SELECT q.DistrictCode, 
  q.District_Name AS District,
  sum(case when q.StrategicResponse = 'yourResponse1' then q. Bene_Act end) SumResponse1,
  sum(case when q.StrategicResponse = 'yourResponse2' then q. Bene_Act end) SumResponse2,
  sum(case when q.StrategicResponse = 'yourResponse3' then q. Bene_Act end) SumResponse3,
  sum(case when q.StrategicResponse = 'yourResponse4' then q. Bene_Act end) SumResponse4
FROM QryMainCrosstab q
WHERE q.Month = yourValue
GROUP BY q.DistrictCode, q.District_Name
```

You would replace your actual values of the `StrategicResponse` with each of the `'yourResponse1'`, etc. You would also still need to pass into this query the Month that you want to filter in the `WHERE` clause.